# how to load a value from database in radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I need to know if you can do this function ... I have a database that has a "boolean" field that accepts 0 or 1 values And I have an HTML page in which there is a radioButton with values Ok or No I must be able to load the boolean value in the radioButton so if in the database the boolean variable is 1 on the HTML page (after executing the SELECT) the radioButton will have OK value if in the database the boolean variable is 0 on the HTML page (after executing the SELECT) the radioButton will have NO value

this is the code of my attempts :

```html
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "progettocantiere";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$idAffidataria = $_GET['idAffidataria'];

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Affidataria WHERE idAffidataria = '{$idAffidataria}'";



    $result = $conn->query($sql1);


    $details = $result->fetch_array();




    $savedNomeCantiere = $details["nomeCantiere"];
    $savedAddettoSicurezza = $details["addettoSicurezza"];
    $savedMailAffidataria = $details["mailAffidataria"];
    $savedContrattoDiAppalto = $details["contrattoDiAppalto"]; // <--- BOOLEAN <----
                 
        



$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

echo($nomeCantiere);

?>


<html>
<body>

<table>
 <tr>
    
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Cantiere</td>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="cantiereAffidataria" id="cantiereAffidataria" value="<?php echo $savedNomeCantiere; ?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">ContrattoDiAppalto</td>
  <td bgcolor="#B35556"><form action="">
    

       OK <input type="radio" name="contrattoDiAppalto" id="contrattoDiAppalto" value="<?php echo $savedContrattoDiAppalto; ?>" onchange="color(this)" /> <BR>
        NO  <input type="radio" name="contrattoDiAppalto" id="contrattoDiAppalto" value="<?php echo $savedContrattoDiAppalto; ?>" onchange="color(this)" checked/>
       
   
</form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in other words I have to be able to change the radioButton according to the data provided by the SELECT on the database

I tried to give it the value through `<?php echo $savedContrattoDiAppalto; ?>"` but I doubt it's right .. I'm running out of ideas .. can someone help me?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You cannot have the same `id` in a DOM. All `id` must be unique. Setting the `radio` to the same `value` for both choices will result in unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make an variable `$checked = 'checked'`

Then make an condition to check if it's 1 or 0

```
$checked = 'checked';
if($savedContrattoDiAppalto != 1){
    $checked = ''; // Default is checked, if it isn't 1 then it's empty and will not check your radio.
}
```

And apply that variable to your input attributes.

```
    <input type="radio" name="contrattoDiAppalto" id="contrattoDiAppalto" 
value="<?php echo $savedContrattoDiAppalto; ?>" onchange="color(this)" $checked/>
```

Full code should be :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "progettocantiere";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$idAffidataria = $_GET['idAffidataria'];

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Affidataria WHERE idAffidataria = '{$idAffidataria}'";



    $result = $conn->query($sql1);


    $details = $result->fetch_array();




    $savedNomeCantiere = $details["nomeCantiere"];
    $savedAddettoSicurezza = $details["addettoSicurezza"];
    $savedMailAffidataria = $details["mailAffidataria"];
    $savedContrattoDiAppalto = $details["contrattoDiAppalto"];
    $checked = 'checked';             
    if($savedContrattoDiAppalto != true){
        $checked = ''; // if not true then not checked
    }    



$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

echo($nomeCantiere);

?>


<html>
<body>

<table>
 <tr>

    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Cantiere</td>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="cantiereAffidataria" id="cantiereAffidataria" value="<?php echo $savedNomeCantiere; ?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">ContrattoDiAppalto</td>
  <td bgcolor="#B35556"><form action="">


       OK <input type="radio" name="contrattoDiAppalto" id="contrattoDiAppalto" value="<?php echo $savedContrattoDiAppalto; ?>" onchange="color(this)"  $checked/> <BR>
        NO  <input type="radio" name="contrattoDiAppalto" id="contrattoDiAppalto" value="<?php echo $savedContrattoDiAppalto; ?>" onchange="color(this)" $checked/>


</form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand :(

Comment: I tried to update the code of my project, but it does not work